# I have two select boxes. I want to enable second select box only if i click a particular option in first select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, dropdown

I have two select boxes. I want to enable second select box only if i click a particular option in first select box. 
Below given is my two select boxes code, and if i select the 'Admin' option on the 'usertype' select box, then only i want to enable the entire 'zone' select box. I had coded for this result as given below using jquery. But not working.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('[name="usertype"]').change(function(){
    $('[name="zone"]').prop('enabled', this.value=='Admin');
    });
</script>

<select name="usertype">
    <option>President</option>
    <option>Secretary</option>
    <option>Treasurer</option>
    <option>Admin</option>                                              
</select>

<select name="zone">
    <option>North Zone</option>
    <option>South Zone</option>
    <option>East Zone</option>
    <option>West Zone</option>  
</select>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+disable+second+dropdown

Comment: Not to disable a single 'option' in second dropdown. The requirement is to disable the enitre second selectbox itself when selecting all other options in first select box except one option.

Comment: The collection of codes should teach you any way to disable.

Comment: I think this will help you.   https://jsfiddle.net/tazbirul/kx20w9c7/#

Comment: @TazbirulHaque when i tried your code, it keeps the second select box to be disabled always.

Comment: @MaheshAR i have used this code and its working.

Comment: your answer section is disabled that's why i cannot post my code here

Comment: @TazbirulHaque The jquery library you used is same as of https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js or different one?

Comment: @MaheshAR i have used  https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mohammedshafeek/843xq6t8/1/

Comment: @TazbirulHaque Thanks. It worked. But a small issue. Once we select admin from usertype selectbox, it enables the zone selectbox. But again if we clicked anyother option on the usertype selectbox other than Admin option, then also the zone select box is in enabled mode. It has to go back to disabled mode if changed the usertype option to president or secretary or treasurer.

Comment: @MohammedShafeek Thanks. But the actual requirement is just reverse of what you coded. Whenever we select Admin option from usertype select box, then only zone select box to be enabled. When selecting all other options in usertype select box like president or secretary or treasurer, then the zone selectbox should be in disabled mode :)

Comment: @MohammedShafeek. just reversed your if else statements in the script satisfies the requirement. Thank you once again. :)

Comment: @മഹേഷ്‌ ..you should have get it when you searched well..always try to write scripts in footer. That's best standard. And the worst thing u did was u called ur events before it renders.So if u write in head..write inside jqaury body onload function. That's it was not hitting..